# Send request by JSON or String what get less resources

Tags: json, string, request, http-post

Actually question is not important.

For example there data to send by post request as:

```
{data: {"asd":"asdasd", "asd1":"asd1asd1"}}
```

Is something change if send it as string like:

```
{data: '{"asd":"asdasd", "asd1":"asd1asd1"}'}
```

or if is possible (string only):

```
'{data: {"asd":"asdasd", "asd1":"asd1asd1"}}'
```

So question is what type of those will get less resources or it will the same even with large data?

Answer (score 0):

The longer your string is, the more bandwidth will it use. In which schema you need to send your data only depends on the receiver.

The only differences you have in your examples above are whether you send them as text or JSON. In the end, it will be sent as a string as the body of a HTTP Post request always is sent as a string, which means the bandwidth does not depend on how you send your object as it always will be a string. The receiver will then create a JSON object out of it upon receiving.

As you probably have the object as a javascript object (or whichever language you use) in your client where you'll send the request from, just use the JSON object whenever possible. The library you use should make sure that it takes a performant way of translating it to a string.